# Cygwin1.dll c++ application error

Tags: c++, cygwin

I have finished my compiler project https://github.com/nibblebits/craft-compiler

The problem is when I make a release it requires a lot of DLL files Cygwin1.dll included. Even though I copy them to the local folder that the application runs in, it still shows me the same problem.

How can I get around this issue?

Thanks

Comment: error while loading shared libraries: cygstdc++-6.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Also do other systems like MYSYS also require a DLL to be in the bin directory when releasing the software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I had two directories with the same files, the command prompt was in the one I was not modifying leading me to not understand why copying the DLL's to the local directory had no affect.